# Convert user inputs to specific class instances

Tags: java, class, instantiation

### Background

Users type information into web form inputs such as:

```
<input type="text" name="report_name" value="First name" />
<select name="report_date_birthday">
  <option value="2038-01-19">Jan 19, 2038</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" name="report_array_colour[]" value="Blue" />Blue
<input type="checkbox" name="report_array_colour[]" value="Red" />Red
```

These values are eventually passed into reporting software. The reporting software API requires name-value pairs with the names as `String` instances and the values as Java classes.

### Problem

A subclass implements an abstract method (that associates user input types with Java classes) as follows:

```
private static final String REPORT_VARIABLE_PREFIX = "report_";

protected Map<String, Class<?>> getPrefixes() {
  Map<String, Class<?>> map = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();

  map.put( REPORT_VARIABLE_PREFIX + "", java.lang.String.class );
  map.put( REPORT_VARIABLE_PREFIX + "int_", java.lang.Integer.class );
  map.put( REPORT_VARIABLE_PREFIX + "float_", java.math.BigDecimal.class );
  map.put( REPORT_VARIABLE_PREFIX + "array_", java.util.List.class );
  map.put( REPORT_VARIABLE_PREFIX + "date_", java.util.Date.class );
  map.put( REPORT_VARIABLE_PREFIX + "time_", java.sql.Time.class );
  map.put( REPORT_VARIABLE_PREFIX + "timestamp_", java.sql.Timestamp.class );

  return map;
}
```

All user inputs are submitted as `java.lang.String` values, except `report_array_` values.

### Questions

Ignoring `report_array_` input values:

1. What is the most efficient way to instantiate the Java classes that are mapped to user input types using the values provided by the user?
2. Is there a better mechanism to map the user input types such that instantiating their representative classes is easier to implement?
3. Is there a better way to represent the user input types within the web form?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I have found to convert the values is by doing it manually:

```
protected Object convertValue( String prefix, String value ) {
  Class<?> c = getPrefixes().get( prefix );
  Object result = value;

  try {
    if( c == java.lang.String.class ) {
      result = new String( value );
    }
    else if( c == java.sql.Timestamp.class ) {
      result = Timestamp.valueOf( value );
    }
    else if( c == java.sql.Time.class ) {
      result = Time.valueOf( value );
    }
    else if( c == java.util.Date.class ) {
      DateFormat sdf = createDateFormat();
      result = sdf.parse( value );
    }
    else if( c == java.math.BigDecimal.class ) {
      result = new BigDecimal( value );
    }
    else if( c == java.lang.Integer.class ) {
      result = Integer.valueOf( value );
    }
    else if( prefix.equalsIgnoreCase( PARAM_VARIABLE_PREFIX + "array_int_" ) ) {
      result = parseIntegerArray( value );
    }
  }
  catch( Exception e ) {
    throw new RuntimeException( e );
  }

  return result;
}
```

Note that this implies that the map, then, is not necessary, as it adds an unused layer of complexity:

```
  map.put( REPORT_VARIABLE_PREFIX + "", java.lang.String.class );
  map.put( REPORT_VARIABLE_PREFIX + "int_", java.lang.Integer.class );
  map.put( REPORT_VARIABLE_PREFIX + "float_", java.math.BigDecimal.class );
  map.put( REPORT_VARIABLE_PREFIX + "array_", java.util.List.class );
  map.put( REPORT_VARIABLE_PREFIX + "date_", java.util.Date.class );
  map.put( REPORT_VARIABLE_PREFIX + "time_", java.sql.Time.class );
  map.put( REPORT_VARIABLE_PREFIX + "timestamp_", java.sql.Timestamp.class );
```

Since the map adds no value to the conversion process, it can be removed, which means the `convertValue` method becomes:

```
  protected Object convertValue( String prefix, String value ) {
    Object result = value;

    try {
      if( prefix.equalsIgnoreCase( PARAM_VARIABLE_PREFIX + "" ) ) {
        result = new String( value );
      }
      else if( prefix.equalsIgnoreCase( PARAM_VARIABLE_PREFIX + "timestamp_" ) ) {
        result = Timestamp.valueOf( value );
      }
      // ... etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

Putting the type information into the names of the name-value pairs is a fine way to do it. It allows the process to be automated. For example, you can write a filter that iterates over the request parameters, does the conversion for each, and store the new objects as a request attribute.

Also, each of the classes (which the exception of `List`) contains a `.valueOf(String)` method, which will do most of the conversions for you. You might be better of using a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for creating your time and date objects. This will allow you to sanitize your data.

Comment: There is no "valueOf" interface, so the separate classes cannot be instantiated automatically. Looks like I have to convert the class to its appropriate instance using a cascade of if-else statements.

Comment: @Dave: You can reflect for the `valueOf` and just call it.

Comment: Only three of the classes have a static `valueOf` method.

Comment: @Dave: Correct. So then you would have to use SimpleDataFormat for the dates.